# Download pdf from javascript onclick attribute using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I would like to download a pdf from [this](https://puc.overheid.nl/natuurvergunningen/doc/PUC_746615_17/1/) website using R. The problem is that you first have to click on the "Maak een pdf" button on the website. Because this is an javascript onclick attribute. I'm able to find the attribute but I have no idea how to download this pdf file. Here is an screenshot of the element inspection:

[image]

Here is the code I tried:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

link = "https://puc.overheid.nl/natuurvergunningen/doc/PUC_746615_17/1/"

button <- link %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(".download-als") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") 
button
#> [1] "javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(\"ctl00$cphContent$Main$ctl00$DocumentHeader$ctl00\", \"\", true, \"\", \"\", false, true))"

download.file(button, destfile = "Downloads/test.pdf")
#> Warning in download.file(button, destfile = "Downloads/test.pdf"): URL
#> javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
#> WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphContent$Main$ctl00$DocumentHeader$ctl00", "",
#> true, "", "", false, true)): cannot open destfile 'Downloads/test.pdf', reason
#> 'No such file or directory'
#> Warning in download.file(button, destfile = "Downloads/test.pdf"): download had
#> nonzero exit status
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I tried to `download.file` the file but of course that doesn't work. It seems that we need to use the `RSelenium` to create a click action on the button via a browser. I found this question: [How to web-scrape on-click information with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384594/how-to-web-scrape-on-click-information-with-r) but I can't find a way to do this with an "onclick" attribute. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to download a pdf file from an onclick attribute?

Comment: Hi @KJ, thanks for your comment! But how do you create that link without manually clicking on the button on the website? I'm not completely sure what you mean by set of instructions.

Comment: @Quinten You can see my deleted answer (I do not have the time to correct the mess up, hence, it's deleted). Just inspect the Network calls.

Comment: Hi @MendelG, Thanks for your suggestion! I don't understand how you get the json result as output? Where can we find that to get the url you mention?

Comment: @Quinten You need to inspect your network calls (usually you can press F12) in your browser. and then navigate to the "Network" tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to that final download link from the document page, we need to play some request/response ping-pong to mimic javascript application -- first, we'd need to submit a request to the backend, then wait for it to finish and continue with the download.

To recover that exact flow and used endpoint (`/PUC/Handlers/ManifestatieService.ashx`), we should focus on Network tab of browser's dev tools (activate it before clicking through download process to record all relevant requests/responses); if there's too much traffic, search and filter can be quite handy:
[image: Chrome dev tools]

To implement flow that's close enough, we'll mostly rely on `httr2`; `rvest` is only used to extract JavaScript function parameters from link's `onclick` attribute. Though in this particular case, we could probably extract identifier `PUC_746615_17` and `kanaal` value (`natuurvergunningen`) directly from document URL too.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr2)

# timestamp helper
timestamp_ <- \() sprintf("%.0f", as.numeric(Sys.time()) * 1000)

# get request parameters --------------------------------------------------
link = "https://puc.overheid.nl/natuurvergunningen/doc/PUC_746615_17/1/"

onclick <- 
  link %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements(".download-als a") %>% 
  html_attr("onclick")

(req_param <- str_extract_all(onclick, "(?<=')[^\\s']+(?=')")[[1]])
#> [1] "PUC_746615_17_1"    "natuurvergunningen" "pdf"

# submit request / get ticket ---------------------------------------------
ticket <- 
  request("https://puc.overheid.nl/PUC/Handlers/ManifestatieService.ashx") %>% 
  req_url_query(actie      = "maakmanifestatie",
                kanaal     = req_param[2],
                identifier = req_param[1],
                soort      = req_param[3],
                `_`        = timestamp_()) %>% 
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_json(check_type = FALSE)

jsonlite::toJSON(ticket, auto_unbox = TRUE,  pretty = TRUE)
#> {
#>   "ticket": "70337706-d27d-463e-8b6b-8ca2ba47662d"
#> }

# submit ticket / get url -------------------------------------------------
# it takes few moments for backend to finish our request
Sys.sleep(2)
pdf_url <- 
  request("https://puc.overheid.nl/PUC/Handlers/ManifestatieService.ashx") %>% 
  req_url_query(actie      = "haalstatus",
                ticket     = ticket$ticket,
                `_`        = timestamp_()) %>% 
  req_perform() %>% 
  resp_body_json(check_type = FALSE)

jsonlite::toJSON(pdf_url, auto_unbox = TRUE,  pretty = TRUE)
#> {
#>   "result": {
#>     "status": "available",
#>     "url": "/puc-opendata/request-result/70337706-d27d-463e-8b6b-8ca2ba47662d/Verlenging%20van%20de%20looptijd%20van%20de%20vergunning%20Wet%20Natuurbescherming%20%28Wnb%29%20voor%20het%20project%20Afsluitdij.pdf",
#>     "filename": "Verlenging van de looptijd van de vergunning Wet Natuurbescherming (Wnb) voor het project Afsluitdij.pdf"
#>   }
#> }

# download pdf ------------------------------------------------------------
request("https://puc.overheid.nl/PUC/Handlers/ManifestatieService.ashx") %>% 
  req_url_query(actie = "download",
                identifier = req_param[1],
                url = pdf_url$result$url,
                filename = pdf_url$result$filename) %>% 
  req_perform(path = pdf_url$result$filename)
#> <httr2_response>
#> GET
#> https://puc.overheid.nl/PUC/Handlers/ManifestatieService.ashx?actie=download&identifier=PUC_746615_17_1&url=%2Fpuc-opendata%2Frequest-result%2F70337706-d27d-463e-8b6b-8ca2ba47662d%2FVerlenging%2520van%2520de%2520looptijd%2520van%2520de%2520vergunning%2520Wet%2520Natuurbescherming%2520%2528Wnb%2529%2520voor%2520het%2520project%2520Afsluitdij.pdf&filename=Verlenging%20van%20de%20looptijd%20van%20de%20vergunning%20Wet%20Natuurbescherming%20%28Wnb%29%20voor%20het%20project%20Afsluitdij.pdf
#> Status: 200 OK
#> Content-Type: application/pdf
#> Body: On disk 'body'

fs::file_info(pdf_url$result$filename)[1:3]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   path                                                               type   size
#>   <fs::path>                                                         <fct> <fs:>
#> 1 …nning Wet Natuurbescherming (Wnb) voor het project Afsluitdij.pdf file   171K
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Alternative approaches would be based on tools that can handle JavaScript, i.e. Chromote or RSelenium, for example. And perhaps `webdriver` with PhantomJS.

Comment: Thank you @margusl for your great answer! I am not sure how you got this specific `"https://puc.overheid.nl/PUC/Handlers/ManifestatieService.ashx"`url for the request? Is it possible to do this without manually adding to the request. I have to scrape more documents so manually adding this url is not most useful.

Comment: Updated with a screenshot and some explanaition, its basically the same approach described by @MendelG - recover requests through network tab. `/PUC/Handlers/ManifestatieService.ashx` is a service endpoint  and it's highly unlikely that it will change, you just call it with different actions (`?actie=...`)  and arguments.

Comment: And to clarify, this is a bit special case as you have to go through multiple requests and work with intermediate results as there's no static download link for the pdf document, you first need to ask the backend service to prepare a download for you, which is then available only for a limited time.

Comment: And techincally you can extract used endpoints from the page source as well,  if you search for `manifestatieServiceUrl` or `manifestatieDownloadServiceUrl`, you'll find the relevant javascript block.

Comment: Hi @margusl, thank you very much! Now I understand what you mean. Now I have a file which returns the following error when downloading the pdf code: `Error:
! Failed to open file`. Do you understand what this means? Maybe I ask this as a new question.

Comment: @Quinten , compared to site's javascript logic, my approach is quite naive and without any error handling.  You are free to share the url to that document . Or if you'd rather go for a follow-up question, you can ping me here in the comments. As I don't think I've dealt with such a flow before, I'd actually be interested to see what might have caused it or if there's an easy fix.  .. or if  it just makes sense move from rvest+httr2 to e.g chromote for this.

Comment: @margusl, thanks for your great answer! I just asked a follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77940850/download-pdf-from-javascript-onclick-attribute-using-r).